# Is there any way to compile GnuTLS in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, compilation, ssl

is there? Has anyone ever tried this successfully? If so how can this be done?

Comment: Did it fail for you? With what error messages? GnuTLS is just a software package and Eclipse is just an IDE...

Comment: Why is this tagged with `android`?

Comment: im trying to compile gnutls on android through eclipse

Answer (score 1):

GnuTLS is a C project. Compiling the project means you have installed:
C compiler
Make
makeinfo (or textinfo)

Related projects necessary for compiling GnuTLS are:
libnettle (gnu crypto library)
gmp (precision math library)

You also need to be using the right Eclipse editor C/C++ -> linked here:
[Eclipse Kepler](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr2)

When You have your projects untar-ed, make sure to add each one in eclipse as a new C project with an empty Makefile.

Remember: Build your dependencies first, gmp and nettle.